# How to handle dynamic number of form elements in javaee6

Tags: html, jersey, java-ee-6

Normally we have a static form that is posted on the server and since it's static we know the name of the variables.

But let's say I have a dynamic number of form elements that I need to post, what's the best way to handle it in the backend? Can it be done via jersey?

A best example of this, is paypal's implementation when checking out items. They have dynamic number of inputs that is suffixed with _x, where x is a number.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name_1" />
<input type="text" name="amount_1" />
<input type="text" name="quantity_1" />

<input type="text" name="name_2" />
<input type="text" name="amount_2" />
<input type="text" name="quantity_2" />
</form>
```

How do I read all the input text in the backend?

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read entity as `MultivaluedMap<String, String> form` or `Form form` (which is basically same thing) and iterate all keys or .. whatever you need. See [FormParamTest](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/jersey-tests/src/test/java/com/sun/jersey/impl/methodparams/FormParamTest.java?rev=5717) for example.

Comment: Thanks, I was also able to figured that out when I browse their documentation: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e8